# Mssql database old bakup restored on production server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am using mssql server 2016, I have accidentally restored the 24 hours old database backup file on production server, so I have lost the data for today, means I have lost the data of 24 hours, is there any chance I can get back my original database so that I can bring back the production database to original state, means before restoring the old database on production server.

Comment: probably you have a good question, but you are in the wrong place. You can ask the administration community, StackOverflow is for coding queries.

Comment: Do you have a recent Full backup? Do you have transaction log backups? Do you have any more recent system backups?  Do you have your resume in good order?

Comment: i hope you have your tansaction log backups Read this from ms https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/relational-databases/logs/the-transaction-log-sql-server?view=sql-server-2016

Comment: Does your System Admin team have a snapshot of the disks or the entire machine prior to the restore?

Answer (score 0):

> is there any chance I can get back my original database so that I can bring back the production database to original state

There is NO possibility to do the UNDO/ROLLBACK action from the restore, you got only way to find recent backups that performed before restore operation.

Seems it's been more than 10 hours, if the database not in Full recovery mode and No Log backups, the translations whatever been posted during this 10 hours and happening now would be lost, i think you need quick action plan on this, without wasting time to find UNDO/ROLLBACK methods try to recover from recent backups by taking current state offline to avoid further lose.

Answer (score 0):

You can't undo restore like it did not happen in the first place normally, but if you have a transaction log you can revert to the time before you replaced your database. or use a recent backup, this will minimize date lose.